# calculate the chance level accuracy of multi class imbalanced classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn

Is there an easy way to calculate for each train+test set the chance level accuracy?  my models deal with different data sets that have very large number of classes and they are not uniform distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i figured it out, the way to find the chance level accuracy for multiclass data set with imbalanced classes we can use scikit learn dummy calssifier with the following configuration :

DummyClassifier(strategy='stratified')

“stratified”: generates predictions by respecting the training set’s class distribution." [DummyClassifier on scikit documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.dummy.DummyClassifier.html)